# what is the best way to implement posts that expire after a period of time?

Tags: mongodb, react-native, express

I am working on a react native & MongoDB project that has posts which expire after 7 days from the time of creation. and then change the status to expired.

[image]

I am currently thinking of checking at the start of each day for posts that will expire soon then notify the user, but how would I actually change the status to expired at the exact moment it expires?

**EDIT:**

For people from the future, this is how I did it :)

```
const watchForExpired = () => {
  let interval = setInterval(async () => {
    let dateBeforeSevenDays = new Date();
    dateBeforeSevenDays.setDate(dateBeforeSevenDays.getDate() - 7);

    const listings = await Listing.find({
      $and: [
        {
          creationTime: { $lte: dateBeforeSevenDays },
        },
        {
          status: "approved",
        },
      ],
    });

    if (listings.length === 0) return;

    const updateQuery = await Listing.updateMany(
      { _id: { $in: listings.map(({ _id }) => _id) } },
      { $set: { status: "expired" } },
      { multi: true }
    );
  }, 60000);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your posts have the creationTime as attribute I would get the current time every one minute or so and then check if the creationTime + 7 days is smaller than the current time and if so, remove the post. If you really need it at the EXACT time, you can get performance problems with a lot of posts as you would have to implement potentially multiple timers and they are really heavy.